# Javascript: Which flow type to use for list items in a list containing multiple types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Consider a list of objects containing instances of type `A` and `B`:

```
type A = { type: 1 | 2, foo: string };
type B = { type: 1 | 2, bar: number };
```

To handle item click events, I also have a union type:

```
type ListItem = A | B;
```

Click events are handled in:

```
const handleListItemClicked = (listItem: ListItem) => {
  if (listItem.type === 1) // by convension, 1 === type A
    [...]
};
```

I saw this pattern several places learning javascript and Flow. It seems dangerous to me, as is is *possible* to make type errors which flow will not catch - for example:

```
handleListItemClicked({type: 1, bar: 42}); // will fail
```

What is a good and safe way to solve this kind of problem? Since there are no interfaces or inheritance in Flow, I can only think of wrapping both types (see below) but hope to find a more idiomatic solution.

```
type ListItem2 = {
  a: A,
  b: B,
}
```

Comment: If your convention is that `type == 1` means `A`, then you shouldn't allow `type: 1 | 2` in `A`?

Comment: @Bergi beat me to it. I was actually going to say that `type B = { type: 1 | 2, bar: number };` seems to be wrong, in that case, as it cannot be `1`...apparently.

Comment: **Please note**: the `flow` tag specifically says not to use it. You are probably looking for `flowtype`.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi and @VLAZ, makes sense. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem if `A` and `B` did not have such `type` property? Would one still declare a union type for the list item click handler's parameter?

Comment: Yes, you'd use a union type if you wanted either of the two to be usable.

Comment: @Bergi thanks again. Now (without the `type` property) it would be possible to crash due to a type issue which  Flow can't detect by calling `listItem.foo.toLowerCase()` on a type B instance in `handleListItemClicked`. Is this completely normal use of Flow or bad practice?

Comment: @MartinPoulsen I think flow should be able to detect that mistake, because the type `A | B` doesn't guarantee a `.foo` property to exist. You'd probably need an explicit downcast to `A`. But I don't know, I never used flow myself.

Comment: @Bergi this is what I also expected, but it seems that by `A | B`, Flow actually let's me use any method/property available on either `A` or `B`. 

My question is whether such union declaration - which could lead to undetectable type problems - should be avoided generally.

Comment: @MartinPoulsen it's on a case by case basis. If you have `Group` and `Role` that both contain `User`, then it might make sense to pass around an array of  `Group | Role` members. After all, you are interested in containers for users here. This might be less messy than making each a child of `UserContainer` because inheritance could muck your actual hierarchy up - e.g., `Role` is related with security, while `Group` is a way for users to collect other users into lists. Then making these related makes little sense while a union type is a pain free way to express their relationship.